# How to solve this index out of bound

Tags: java

this is my code, when I am trying this I am getting index out of bound exception. Please suggest

```
while (rs.next()) {
    String url = rs.getString("rssUrl");
    List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
    test.add(url);
    //List<List<String>> output = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    for (int start = 0; start < test.size(); start += 5) {
        List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
        System.out.println(group);
        //System.out.println(output);
        System.out.println("split");
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line there is an exception?

Comment: I would look here : `List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);`

Comment: You have to tell us what you want to do? Why are you breaking the List<String> into sub-list's in sizes of 5?

Comment: I will get 10 elements in 'url' I want to use 5 elements at a time, this is just an example I will get more than 10000 elements in url but i have limited to 10 for testing

Answer (score 4):

Your List test does have only one item at each iteration. Hence, `start + 5` is larger than test.size(). This causes the IndexOutOfBoundException as stated by the JavaDoc:

> IndexOutOfBoundsException for an illegal endpoint index value fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size || fromIndex > toIndex

Comment: @user3291784: You have just one element. If you want to break it into various parts, use substring.

Comment: Do you try to get the first 5 characters from `url`? If, make sure `url.length()` is `>= 5` and use `url.substring(0, 5)` instead

Answer (score 2):

I think this line is the problem:

```
List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
```

`start+5` is going to go beyond the bounds of the list for the last item

Comment: yes problem is at this line List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5); this is the exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 5
 at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:962)
 at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:954)
 at Alerts.IRtest.main(IRtest.java:27)

Comment: Oh if you're still looking for a solution I would advise you to use `Math.min(start+5, test.size())`. This will use start+5 or the size of the array, whichever is the lesser.  Actually you might have to use `test.size()-1`, I'm not completely familary with java.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException in this line

```
List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
```

You are trying to access the 5th element ((start = 0) + 5) in a List that has only 1 element.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you need to reconsider your code

Comment: Your list has only one element. You just declared it and added only one element:  test.add(url);

Comment: ohh yes, it has only one element after completing all the while loop it get 10 elements to it, how do I do this for loop outside while

Comment: You will need to declare the List outside of the while loop, and inside the while loop you will only get the url and add it to your list. So you will put your for loop after the end of the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your condition in the for loop:

```
for (int start = 0; start + 5 < test.size(); start += 5) {
```

The problem is that this line

```
List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
```

goes out of bounds since you are not checking that `start + 5` is smaller than the list size.

Comment: Who gives minuses without a comment?

Comment: The List only has one element. The loop is useless.

Comment: @user3291784 Actually, by the code you have posted, you are incorrect and that's exactly why your error is occurring, as this answer states. And don't be rude.

Comment: I tried this, it neither gave an exception nor gave results

Comment: I fixed this in this way List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (rs.next()) {
    String url = rs.getString("rssUrl");
    test.add(url);
   }
   for (int start = 0; start+2 < test.size(); start += 2) {
       List<String> group = test.subList(start,start+2);
       System.out.println(group);
       //System.out.println(output);
       System.out.println("split");
   } now my problem is I am not getting last list only 8 are coming last two are not coming

Comment: @user3291784: You got lucky.. you didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused on how `subList` works.

`subList` will return a **SUB LIST** from within a **LIST**. So that if you have a `List<String>` with 10 elements, and you say give me a `subList` from 0 to 4, it will return you a `List<String>` with 5 elements.

What you are trying to do is perform some sort of `substring`, which is incorrect to use `subList` for this purpose. Your loop is useless for `subList` because you immediately are going to go out of bounds (as you have already shown) due to the fact that on the first iteration, there is only **ONE** element. Boom, you just killed a baby kitten.

Even if I were to add say, five or six elements in the beginning - your for loop is still wrong for this purpose. For example,

```
       String url = "http://www.google.com";
       List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
       test.add(url);
       test.add(url);
       test.add(url);
       test.add(url);
       test.add(url);
       test.add(url);

       for (int start = 0; start < test.size(); start += 5) 
       {
          System.out.println("start = " + start);
          List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
          System.out.println(group);          
       }
```

Output:

```
start = 0
[http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com, http://www.google.com]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 10
start = 5
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:922)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:914)
    at javaapplication2.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So you can see how your `subList` fails and your logic is wrong.

Implement a `subString` but ensure that you don't go beyond the length of your string when you break your `String` that you added to your `List<String>`.

Answer (score -1):

In your for loop, you are incrementing start variable by 5 after every iteration. The condition defined in the for loop, will check before every iteration that the index deos not overshoot the total size of the list. But inside the for loop, you are again incrementing the start variable by 5 and accessing the list using this variable, which could be beyond the size of the list causing an out of bounds exception.

for eg. size of list is 17 and you are in the second iteration, so you enter the for loop with the start having a value of 15. But inside the for loop, you increment the variable again by 5, making it to 20. If you try accessing the 20th element of the list, it will definitely throw an out of bound exception.

**EDIT:**

```
for (int start = 0; start < test.size(); start += 5) {
    if((start+5)<=index.size()){
       List<String> group = test.subList(start, start+5);
       System.out.println(group);
       //System.out.println(output);
       System.out.println("split");
    }else{
       break;
    }        
}
```

Comment: I think what you said is exactly correct, can you tell me how do I fix this

Comment: Just put your subList line inside an if block which checks if the start variable value is less than the list size.

Comment: putting for loop outside while and putting for statement like this worked for me for (int start = 0; start <= test.size(); start += 5)